# Go: error serving html template

Tags: go

Is there something wrong with the way I'm serving the html template below? Nothing appears on the page.

twitter.go:

```
func loghandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t := template.Must(template.New("tele").ParseFiles("layout/log.html"))
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

log.html:

```
<html>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="Username" name="name"></input>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form> 
</html>
```

Directory structure:

```
twitter
     layout
          log.html
twitter.go
```

Comment: did you check for errors?

Comment: `if err := t.Execute(w, nil); err != nil { panic(err) }`

Comment: it says html/template:tele: "tele" is an incomplete or empty template

Comment: the previous error msg was: open layout/log.html: no such file or directory

Comment: ok resolved. Posted an answer below.

Comment: The silent down vote fairies are annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured, one way to do this:

log.html:

```
{{define "log"}}
<html>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
<label for="name">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="Username" name="name"></input>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form> 
</html>
{{end}}
```

twitter.go:

```
func loghandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t := template.Must(template.New("tele").ParseFiles("layout/log.html"))
    if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "log", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid parsing templates in your handlers. Read this (http://elithrar.github.io/article/approximating-html-template-inheritance/) and http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html to bring yourself up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use something simple like this:

```
func loghandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t,_ := template.ParseFiles("layout/log.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

I have tried it and it works.